# Rasterize and export 3d graphic

Tags: plotting, rendering

I want to Rasterize a 3D model, for which I need a high count of Plotpoints.
I rasterize the graphic and export it as a pdf in the following way:

```
regionmemberfunction = RegionMember[Cone[{{0, 0, -250}, {0, 0, -10}}, 40]];

raster = Rasterize[RegionPlot3D[regionmemberfunction[{x, y, z}], {x, -65, 65}, {y, -65,65}, {z, -260, 5}, PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotRange -> {{-65, 65}, {-65, 65}, {-260, 5}}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {Infinity, 0, 0}, ImageSize -> 200, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.2], Green}], RasterSize -> 1000, ImageSize -> 200]

Export["raster.pdf", raster]
```

The result looks good, but has visible ugly meshlines.

[image]

I think this is a problem of the 3D rendering. If I change the 3DRenderingMehod in the Preferences the problem disappears, but every method has its own litte problems. So what can I do?

**EDIT:**
The problem is not coming from Rasterization, but definitely from 3D rendering. So plotting just the RegionPlot3D without rasterization has the same issue with the visible line in the notebook:

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using ``Graphics3D[Cone[...]]`` directly?

Comment: This is just a minimal example, which shows the effect. I have a large dataset I want to visuallize.

Comment: An alternative would be to use "BSPTree" as "3DRenderingMethod" instead. But compared to "Automatic" it produces very ugly shadows with my data (very high contrasts and unnaturally looking). Changing the lighting accordingly is also no option, since one rendering takes 10min and I have many datasets. So an alternative answer to removing the meshlines resulting from "HardwareDepthPeeling", which is the "3DRenderingMethod" used automaticly, would be to have better shadows (compareable with "HardwareDepthPeeling") for "BSPTree".

Comment: Try adding `Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> False}` to `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: When I made `RasterSize->2000` the problem did not appear. Win10/Mma13.2

Comment: @Alexei changing the RasterSize is not a good solution. By chance it can happen that no line is present in the rasterization, but this is no reliable solution.

Comment: @ihojnicki your solution works great! Thank you very much! Could you please write an answer in which you explain what RelieveDPZFighting does and why it works? Also for you to collect the bounty!